# SQL query multiply decimal

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to multiply two values.  One is a decimal and one is numeric.

Example - Total is what I want:

```
Number   Decimal   Total
900       1.111    999.9
800       1.25     1000
460       4.25     1955
```

In my Sql query, I've tried the following:

```
(ISNUMERIC(UpgradeEmptyNodesPercentageLimitForAllocation) * RawTotalNodes) as ExpectedEmptyNodeCountForUpgrade
```

However, it always returns Number.  How do the above?

Thanks...

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: ISNUMERIC function returns 1 if UpgradeEmptyNodesPercentageLimitForAllocation evaluates to valid numeric datatype otherwise 0, why are you multiplying the result of the function with RawTotalNodes

Comment: I meant to change UpgradeEmptyNodesPercentageLimitForAllocation should have been Decimal and RawTotalNodes = Number.  

When I remove ISNUMERIC... I get 

Conversion failed when converting the ****** value '******' to data type ******.

Comment: We are not seeing the entire picture here, please provide more info. Your code does not reflect sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the scale on your data types, if they are zero then SQL will remove the decimals

```
DECLARE @d1 DECIMAL(18,0) = 1.111
DECLARE @d2 DECIMAL(18,10) = 1.111


SELECT @d1,@d2
```

Answer (score 0):

`ISNUMERIC` is really for evaluating strings, not number types -- and it only returns `0` or `1`.  I think what you want to do is a `CAST` of your numeric and/or decimal values to one with more precision, and then multiply.  What is affecting the operation is the precision and scale of both factors to your operation, as-stored.

These types, by name, are actually interchangeable - but precision and scale are not.

Try casting both to a `NUMERIC` of some acceptabe precision and scale, and then multiplying.  Or, if you don't have a precision and scale that will always work, then cast to `REAL`, if that's an option.

[Read more on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx).